# How can i avoid key and value headers when Copying JSON into snowflake using ORC file format

Tags: csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, orc

Copying into Snowflake using CSV files is loading a JSON column as required.
When loading the same JSON column using ORC files we are seeing headers and additional double-quotes.

When loaded with csv data shows as

```
{
"code":"user"
 },
 {
   "clear": "{"id":"100","add_id":"188","ac_id":"pecid[318]"}"
 }
```

When loaded with ORC the data shows up as

```
"[
 {
   ""key"": ""code"",
   ""value"": ""user""
 },
 {
   ""key"": ""clear"",
   ""value"": ""{\""id\"":\""100\"",\""add_id\"":\""188\"",\""ac_id\"":\""pecid[318]\""}""
 }
 ]"
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow.  Do you mean you're loading the data into a VARIANT column? ORC is an open source columnar format which is going to be pretty similar to Parquet in Snowflake so this doc might help: 
 https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/script-data-load-transform-parquet.html

Another useful article here as well:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/semistructured-considerations.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are well, it sounds like what you are asking how to load ORC files avoiding the double quotes. Did you specify the TYPE = ORC when you uploaded the data?

You can customize the file type as well, and select that type to make sure that the format loads correctly. Unfortunately it looks like the file type does not have any type options. [This question is a good starting point for loading ORC files](https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/question/0D50Z000089ElnfSAC/how-to-copy-orc-file-into-table) since there this is the file type specification for loading orc files [2](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#type-orc)

Comment: Yes i did load the data into the table using the above page you mentioned inspite of which i see the key and value additional headers